# What are the possible reasons my Pentax K-r malfunctions when using flash?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, pentax

I have a Pentax K-r. It works fine in general. But, when I try to use flash, it doesn't take pictures anymore. The shutter will not fire.

What can be the possible causes? Is there a hope to repair it?

Comment: You are talking about the built-in flash, right? Can you find an external flash and insert that into the shoe on top of the camera to see if that flash works with the camera? That might tell us if the internal flash is broken or it's something else. Also, does the camera tell you that the flash is ready at all?

Comment: Pop-up flash or an external one? What camera mode are you in? What lens?

Answer (score 1):

Check the custom option "Release While Charging".
Check the batteries  (camera and/or flash)

If the option is **not** checked, you will not be able to take a picture until the flash is ready.

The flash can take some times to charge if the batteries are not fully recharged (both for the internal flash and the external flash).

Check the manual at pages 81, 150 and 309 : http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/support/man-pdf/k-r.pdf